# ExtJS grid not binding when adding a new property to JSON string

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am getting the following JSON string as response from my restful WCF service:

{"GetAlbumResult":[{"AlbumList":[{"artist":"Kanjoliya","id":128,"name":"Gopal"},{"artist":"Kapoor","id":143,"name":"Lalit"},{"artist":"Ayachit","id":138,"name":"Madhukar"},{"artist":"Chouhan","id":142,"name":"Manish"},{"artist":"Narayanan","id":146,"name":"Manoj"}],"results":5}]}

and this is my code to bind the ExtJS grid:

```
  Ext.define('DHT.store.Users', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'DHT.model.User',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            timeout: 120000,
            noCache: false,
            api: {
                read: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/GetAlbum',
                create: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/AddAlbum',
                update: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/UpdateAlbum',
                destroy: 'http://localhost:52984/ExtJsRestfulService.svc/DeleteRecord'
            },

            reader:
            {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'AlbumList',
                successProperty: 'success'
            },

            writer:
            {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: true
            },
            afterRequest: function (request, success) {
                var obj = new DHT.controller.Users();
                if (request.action == 'read') {
                    obj.readCallback(request);
                }

                else if (request.action == 'create') {
                    obj.createCallback(request);
                }

                else if (request.action == 'update') {
                    obj.updateCallback(request);
                }

                else if (request.action == 'destroy') {
                    obj.deleteCallback(request);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

My grid is not populating. What is it that is not properly configured. Prior to adding "results" properties the grid was working fine. I wanted to add custom paging so I added this property on my service layer. What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the data you want to load is nested now, try changing

```
root: 'AlbumList'
```

to:

```
root: 'GetAlbumResult[0].AlbumList'
```

Comment: GetAlbumList is an array, should be `GetAlbumResult[0]`.